# Remove DataTables default search label when changing language

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm using the internationalisation plug-in for translation (which works fine), for the search placeholder I use a my own translation service (also works fine). The default search label is not something I want to show. I'm able to get what i want with with the following code:

```
$('#example').DataTable({
  language: {
    url: getCurrentLanguage()),
    search: "_INPUT_",
    searchPlaceholder: ownTranslationService("searchPlaceholder"),
    ...
  }
})
```

The problem rises when I change language. When any option other than English the options returns to their default value. In this example the placeholder is still correct but the search parameter goes back to default. I.e. the same if i hadn't declared `search: "_INPUT_"`

Comment: It sounds like you would like a mix of the values from a language file, with one or more of your own customizations. You can have full control by (a) using a local JSON file, instead of a file at the end of a URL, or (b) embedding everything into the DataTables definition - see [here](https://datatables.net/reference/option/language). In either case, you can also add the `searchPlaceholder` option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok with help of the comment I solved the problem. What I failed to realise is that url replaces the all modifications with a completly new object.

I took a third approach as using JSON files in my project is really inconvenient. 
I simply took the translation and put them in as constants in a js file. Did some modification and then returned it as an object. Later to be called with:

```
oLanguage: getCurrentLanguage(), 
...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var table = $('#datatable').DataTable({


        searching: false,
})
```

Comment: Think you misunderstood me, I don't want to remove the searchability of the table but rather just remove the label (which works fine when displaying in default language, but not when switching language)